# how to design authentication and authorization service?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, authorization

I wang to do a website and need to implement a regist and login service firstly. I use spring boot and adopt grpc for the communication between different services.
Here is mine demands:

1. some api may be accessiable just afer user have login
2. I do not want use session, jwt is mine first choice
3. I need to support third party login, like github, google login

Is it suitable to adopt Spring security oauth2 and jwt?  In mature commercial applications, what technology stack is generally used to implement permission authentication?

Comment: using a JWT as a session token is very insecure and not recommended. JWT where never meant to be used as session holders. They are merely a token format, if you want a secure application, you should be using oauth2 or open ID connect, and never pass the JWT to the client, instead pass AT tokens and RT tokens to the client, or passing secured cookies to the client to hold the session, as cookies have built in security features that JWTs just dont have

Comment: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your question, you are on the right track with your investigation. It is a good idea to use Spring Security for such needs.
In the commercial applications I've worked for, we've used third-party services like Firebase Authentication or Auth0 **+** JWT passed via the request header *Authorization:* (Bearer authentication) **+** Spring Security.
After not huge configurations and tunes (and some method overrides) you will
be able to use convenient annotation(s) like `@PreAuthorize()` with arguments `isAuthenticated()`, `permitAll()`, `hasRole(String role)` and so on.

```java
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public List<GiftCardResponse> getUserGiftCards() {
        ...
    }
```